# How do I add asp:dropdownlists dynamically with custom items pulled from DB?

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net

This problem will ultimately be multiple in one, as I have tried a few methods, each with their own problems.

On page load, I am creating a ul with li's inside containing information pulled from a database about shoes (name, desc, price etc). 
I also want a asp:dropdownlist to be added to each li which is populated with the value of shoesize.shoesizeID, and the text of size.sizeSize

Image of the relationship for this part of DB can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBhm4.jpg

At the moment, I am creating it all through making a string, but if I apply it as the .InnerHtml of a div, it doesn't have any of my css applied to it... So I have applied it to a asp:label which made the css load at least... But I cannot seem to even place a blank asp:dropdownlist into this, as it doesn't appear, despite being in the page source.

the other method was using asp:DataList, and databinding the shoes to it. This allowed me to get as far as creating a blank ddl inside of each shoe, but I couldn't figure out how to run my custom queries for each one, to retrieve the unique shoeSize data for that specific shoe, inside of the ItemTemplate.

This is the query:

```
string querySize = "SELECT size.[sizeSize], shoesize.[shoesizeID] FROM [shoe], [shoesize], [size] WHERE shoe.[shoeID] = " + row[0].ToString() + " AND shoe.[shoeID] = shoesize.[shoesizeShoeID] AND shoesize.[shoesizeShoeID] = size.[sizeID]";
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, as I clearly don't know what I'm doing with asp.net...

Comment: Post your code which you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try to  load all of your data into a repeater control. Then modify the query so that all the data is pulled from the data base with respect to the corresponding shoes.

For example:

```
string querySize = "SELECT shoe.[shoeName], shoe.[shoePrice], shoe.[shoeDescription], size.    [sizeSize], shoesize.[shoesizeID] FROM [shoe], [shoesize], [size] 
WHERE shoe.[shoeID] = shoesize. [shoesizeShoeID] AND shoesize.[shoesizeShoeID] = size.[sizeID]";
```